# How to optimize a wxpython GUI (without threading preferably)? hints for code below?

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, wxpython

My GUI with following code does not have threads.The image display hogs up lots of memory and GUI is blocked ,and I can only call one function at a time.Please suggest simple hacks to make the GUI faster.Anyways The Image processing tasks like Clustering takes 5-6 mins.

```
import wx
import sys
import os
import matplotlib
import OpenGL
import PIL
import time
from spectral.graphics.hypercube import hypercube
from spectral import *
init_graphics()

class RedirectText(object):
 def __init__(self,awxTextCtrl):
    self.out=awxTextCtrl

def write(self,string):
    self.out.WriteText(string)            


 class Frame(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self, title,*args,**kwargs):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=title, size=       (1000,85),style=wx.MINIMIZE_BOX|wx.CLOSE_BOX|wx.RESIZE_BORDER|wx.SYSTEM_MENU|wx.CAPTION|wx.CLIP_CHILDREN)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)
    panel=wx.Panel(self,-1)
    self.button=wx.Button(panel,label="Open",pos=(0,0),size=(50,30))
    self.button1=wx.Button(panel,label="Save",pos=(51,0),size=(50,30))
    self.button2=wx.Button(panel,label="ROI",pos=(102,0),size=(50,30))
    self.button3=wx.Button(panel,label="Tone",pos=(153,0),size=(50,30))
    self.slider=wx.Slider(panel,pos=(204,0))
    self.button4=wx.Button(panel,label="Header",pos=(305,0),size=(50,30))
    self.button5=wx.Button(panel,label="Cluster",pos=(356,0),size=(50,30))
    self.button6=wx.Button(panel,label="Cube",pos=(407,0),size=(50,30))
    self.button7=wx.Button(panel,label="Gaussian",pos=(458,0),size=(50,30))
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCubeClick,self.button5)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnHeadClick,self.button4)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnSaveClick,self.button1)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButtonClick,self.button)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCClick,self.button6)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnGClick,self.button7)
    #self.std=wx.TextCtrl(panel,pos=(0,31), size=(500,-1))
    self.loc=wx.TextCtrl(panel,pos=(700,0), size=(300,-1))
    self.status = wx.TextCtrl(panel,-1,'Choose file',pos=(800,22),size=(200,-1))
    #redir=RedirectText(self.std)
    #sys.stdout=redir


def OnButtonClick(self,event):
    wild="HSi Files|*.lan*|All Files|*.*"
    dlg=wx.FileDialog(self,message="Choose a File",wildcard=wild,style=wx.FD_OPEN)
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        self.loc.SetValue(dlg.GetPath())
        dlg.Destroy()
        self.Onview()

def Onview(self):
    filepath=self.loc.GetValue()
    img=image(filepath)
    time.sleep(1)
    view(img)
    time.sleep(1)
    self.status.SetValue('View Ready')



def OnHeadClick(self,event):

    filepath=self.loc.GetValue()
    img=image(filepath)
    self.status.SetValue(img.shape)

def OnCubeClick(self,event):
    time.sleep(0.2)
    self.status.SetValue('Clustering')
    filepath=self.loc.GetValue()
    img= image(filepath).load()
    (m, c) = cluster(img, 20)
    view_indexed(m)
    self.status.SetValue('Clustering View Ready')

def OnCClick(self,event):
    self.status.SetValue('Cube view')
    time.sleep(5)
    filepath=self.loc.GetValue()
    img= image(filepath).load()
    hypercube(img, bands=[29, 19, 9])

def OnGClick(self,event):
    self.status.SetValue('Gaussian procesing')
    time.sleep(30)
    filepath=self.loc.GetValue()
    gt=image(filepath).read_band(0)
    img=image(filepath)
    classes = create_training_classes(img,gt)
    gmlc = GaussianClassifier(classes)
    clMap = gmlc.classify_image(img)
    view_indexed(clMap)
    self.status.SetLabel('Gaussian Ready')


def OnSaveClick(self,event):
    self.status.SetValue('Save File')
    wild="HSi Files|*.lan*|All Files|*.*"
    dlg=wx.FileDialog(self,message="Save AS",wildcard=wild,style=wx.FD_SAVE|wx.FD_OVERWRITE_PROMPT)
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        path=dlg.GetPath()
        self.Save(path)
        self.file=path
        dlg.Destroy()


def OnClose(self, event):
    dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, 
        "Do you really want to close BBvw ?",
        "Confirm Exit", wx.OK|wx.CANCEL|wx.ICON_QUESTION)
    result = dlg.ShowModal()
    dlg.Destroy()
    if result == wx.ID_OK:
        self.Destroy()




  app = wx.App(redirect=False)
  top = Frame("BBvw")
  top.Show()
  app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long running processes should always go into separate threads. Otherwise they will block the GUI's mainloop. If displaying the image is taking up lots of memory, then I'm guessing you're displaying high res photos at full resolution. Try creating a set of lower resolution photos for displaying instead (like thumbnails or something). Unless you need the full resolution displayed, don't do it.

Comment: how should I display images at low res?

Comment: Use PIL to create some lower res versions either on disk or in memory

Comment: Thank you.I was planning to use PyPy ;it is not available for 64 bit windows and now I am planning to use PyOpenCL to help with image processing so that I can take advantage of the GPU.Do you think there will be a significant difference in speeds.Since my project is academic i can experiment a little bit.Threading is the obvious way out , but I want other ways to optimize speed of processing.

Comment: Um...I saw on the PyPy blog that they had somehow gotten wxPython to run on it, so in theory that might speed things up for you too. I know some people will take tough stuff and re-write it in C and then wrap it in Python, but I think that's a little extreme for this.